# POST request on REST API with Jersey not updating the list in the repository, i.e. not adding the new object that is posted

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, postman

I am working a project to create a REST API for sharing a ride application. I am using Jersey to implement it, and running it on a Tomcat server. I have created a RideRepository class which creates a new ride, and get all the rides available. My GET request to get all the rides is working perfectly fine. For creating a new ride and adding it into the list of rides, the POST request is getting the response back (so no error). This should update my rides list. But, when I do a GET request to get all the rides, the new ride that was added does not appear in the response. I used Postman to run this requests.
Here is my code for RideRepository that creates a ride, and get all the rides.

```
public class RideRepository 
{

    List<Ride> rides;

    public RideRepository() {
        rides = new ArrayList<>();

        Ride r1 = new Ride();
        r1.setRid(1);
        r1.setName("Chintan");

        Ride r2 = new Ride();
        r2.setRid(2);
        r2.setName("Tejasvi");

        rides.add(r1);
        rides.add(r2);

    }

    public List<Ride> getRides() {
        return rides;
    }

    public void createRide(Ride r3) {
        rides.add(r3); 
    }
}
```

This is my code for RideResource that do the GET and POST request.

```
@Path("rides")
public class RideResource {

    RideRepository repo = new RideRepository();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Ride> getRides() 
    {
        return repo.getRides();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("ride")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Ride createRide(Ride r1) 
    {
        System.out.println(r1);
        repo.createRide(r1);    
        return r1;
    }
}
```

Here, r3 should be added to the rides List, and when I do GET request after, I should get the updated list with r3 added to it. Any answers are welcomes.

**Update**: I added this line in createRide function to check if the third ride is actually added to the list: `System.out.println(rides);`. And, the updated list does contain the ride that was created. But, it still does not show up when I call GET request to get all rides.

Comment: How is the repo instance initiated in the controller? Is a singleton?

Comment: Yes, the repo instance is singleton. This is how it looks `RideRepository repo = new RideRepository();`

Comment: also the controller?

Comment: I don' think I am creating an instance for the controller. I gets called using the ServletContainer.